# Django Prevent Customers From Buying A Different Paid Membership If They Currently Have One

Tags: python, django, logic, stripe-payments

I am having trouble figuring out the logic of my code to be able to prevent customers from buying another membership if they currently have one already (see image links below). For example, if they are paying for a Professional Membership, I do not want them to be able to click the Select button for Enterprise. If they are an Enterprise paying customer, I do not want them to be able to pay for a Professional Membership. I also do not want customers to be able to type into the address bar  /memberships/payment/ payment page to be able to pay for a different membership. If I could at least prevent the Select button from showing up on the other paid membership that would be a good start.

membership_list.html or /memberships/ url code:

```
        {% for object in object_list %}
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
            <h2>{{ object.membership_type }}</h2>
            <p>Price: ${{ object.price }}<small>/month</small></p>
            <h4>Included Courses</h4>
            <ul>
                {% for course in object.course_set.all %}
                    <li>{{ course.title }}</li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
            {% if object.membership_type != 'Free' %}
            <form method="POST" action="{% url 'memberships:select' %}">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {% if object.membership_type != current_membership %}
                    <button class="btn btn-primary">Select</button>
                {% else %}
                    <small>This is your current membership</small>
                {% endif %}
                <input type="hidden" name="membership_type" value="{{ object.membership_type }}">
            </form>         
            {% endif %} 
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
```

Images:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmnoF.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1Lko.jpg

Views.py and models.py code:

https://dpaste.de/3j53

I would appreciate any help with this.

Comment: get count of the membership with out expired and if count > 1 then hide buttons

Comment: @giveJob Can you go into a little more detail or provide some code on how to do this? What do you mean by expire? I am using Stripe so the membership is either active, canceled, or trialing (rarely) in this case. What field would I use the count on?